# Is $\|x_1 - 2x_2\| \le \sqrt{5} \|x\|$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

Is the following identity true? If so, how?

$$\|x_1-2x_2\| \le \sqrt{5} \|x\|$$

where $x := (x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: It's an instance of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: I don't see how to get from the inequality to this. Do you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: How do you define the norm of the coordinates of a vector?

Comment: The norm I'm using is '2 norm', so norm of x is (x1^2+x2^2)^1/2

Answer (score 2):

For a direct proof, working backwards, we have

$$(2x_1+x_2)^2\geqslant 0 \iff 4x_1^2+4x_1 x_2+x_2^2\geqslant 0 $$

$$\iff (x_1-2x_2)^2\leqslant 5(x_1^2+x_2^2)$$

$$\iff |x_1-2x_2|\leqslant \sqrt{5} ||x||_2.$$

We can also use the **Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**: notice that for $y=(1,-2)$, we have $$|x_1-2x_2|=|\langle x,y\rangle|\leqslant ||x|| ||y||=\sqrt{5}||x||.$$